# what does {1,2} in css background shorthand means

Tags: css

[In some references I found this numbers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZpnoJ.png)

My question is about `{1,2}`

```
<repeat-style> = repeat-x | repeat-y | [ repeat | space | round | no-repeat ]{1,2}
```

what do these numbers mean?

Comment: *This expression may appear once or twice.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-values-4/#mult-num-range):

> A comma-separated pair of numbers in curly braces (`{A,B}`) indicates that the preceding type, word, or group occurs at least `A` and at most `B` times. The `B` may be omitted (`{A,}`) to indicate that there must be at least `A` repetitions, with no upper bound on the number of repetitions.

To this you need to consider [the definition of `|`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-values-4/#comb-one)

> A bar (`|`) separates two or more alternatives: exactly one of them must occur.

so `[repeat | space | round | no-repeat]{1,2}` can give values like:

```
repeat
space
round
no-repeat
```

and also

```
repeat repeat
space repeat
round round
.... (13 more values)
```

Comment: @AmrHendawy why kind of example you want? I already gave you the different values you can get from that syntax

Comment: I don't really know what does it mean {1,2}?
and how can I use it!

Comment: @AmrHendawy I have explained it in my answer, what is not clear? did you follow the links in addition to my explanation?

Comment: Thanks a lot
I got it